# ORACLE Stored Procedure in PHP processing

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have a question regarding stored procedure so I have this procedure saved:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELTESADMIN.TOTALFABRICATION
    (SUBCONT IN VARCHAR, PROJECT IN VARCHAR, TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT OUT NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FABRICATION.MARKING + FABRICATION.CUTTING + FABRICATION.ASSEMBLY + FABRICATION.WELDING + 
            FABRICATION.DRILLING + FABRICATION.FINISHING
    INTO TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT
    FROM FABRICATION
    WHERE SUBCONT_ID = SUBCONT 
        AND PROJECT_NAME = PROJECT;
END;
```

And im processing that in PHP such as,

```
    $subcontValue = "RIYANTO";
    $projectValue = "PROCESSHOUSE";

    $sql = "BEGIN TOTALFABRICATION(:SUBCONT, :PROJECT); END;";
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":SUBCONT", $subcontValue);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":PROJECT", $projectValue);
    oci_define_by_name($stmt, "TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT", $result);

    oci_execute($stmt);

    echo $result;
```

I am sure that all the variables supplied are correct, connection is ok and processable in SQL PLUS
instead, im getting this error in the php side,

> **Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TOTALFABRICATION' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\newEmptyPHP.php on line 39**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure has actually *three* parameters (two `IN`  and one `OUT`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELTESADMIN.TOTALFABRICATION
    (SUBCONT IN VARCHAR, 
     PROJECT IN VARCHAR, 
     TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT OUT NUMBER) AS
```

So, from PHP, you should write that:

```
    $sql = "BEGIN TOTALFABRICATION(:SUBCONT, :PROJECT, :TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT); END;";
    #                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) that *output* parameter to some variable:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, "TOTALFABRICATIONRESULT", $result, 300);
#                                                          ^^^
#                                                        maxlength
```

Please note that according to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php):

> You must specify `maxlength` when using an `OUT` bind so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.